# Certificate issue in Kestrel ssl JSON configuration

Tags: .net-core, ssl-certificate, kestrel-http-server

Referencing to [Kestrel documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.2) is it possible to configure https using appsettings.json file:

```
  "HttpsInlineCertStore": {
    "Url": "https://+:5002",
    "Certificate": {
      "Subject": "<coma separated multi-line subject name>",
      "Store": "Root",
      "Location": "LocalMachine"
  }
```

This certificate exist for sure and next code returns finds it:

```
        using (var certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
        {
            certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            var certificates = certStore.Certificates.Find(
                X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName, "<coma separated multi-line subject name>", true);

            return certificates .Count > 0 ? certificates [0] : null;;
        }
```

At the same time if to search certificate by X509FindType.FindBySubjectName it founds nothing and I believe this is the issue even though [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509findtype?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_X509FindType_FindBySubjectDistinguishedName) says that FindBySubjectDistinguishedName is more specific search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I was able to fix this issue:
 is something like "CN=*name*, C=UK, ..." but if you want to FindBySubjectName you must remove "CN=" from search string and leave only the name so it is looks not like "CN=*name*" but like "*name*".

Comment: Yess! Thank you! I was just about to declare this totally broken when I found your answer.